# How can I access the values of this JSON Array in Python?

Tags: python, node.js, arrays, json

I want to access the values of the following JSON to use them as a google search in my python script. This is the JSON:

```
[
   {"answertext":"300k"},
   {"answertext":"Solo puede ser dividido entre 1 y si mismo"}, 
   {"answertext":"La ciencia que estudia la relacion entre los numeros"}
]
```

This is how I am sending it from my NodeJS server:

```
const pythonPromise = (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const python = spawn("python", ["./patricia/patricia.py", ...data])
        python.stdout.on("data", (data)=> {
            resolve(data.toString())
        })
        python.stderr.on("data", (data)=> {
            reject(data.toString());
        })
    })
}
```

This is how I am trying to access the values the python script:

```
import sys
import json
from googlesearch import search

data = json.dumps(sys.argv[1])
data2 = json.loads(data)

print('Esto es lo que me esta llegando: ' + data2[0]['answertext'])
```

But the only thing I am getting is `"[object Object]"`. Any idea how can I access each `answertext` value?

Comment: Do you get the JSON when you print `sys.argv[1]`?  And it is certain you don't need `data = json.dumps(sys.argv[1])`. If you get JSON try `data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])`

Comment: That's not valid JSON. `answertext` needs to be in quotes: `"answertext"`

Comment: @buran I only get `'object Object'` printing `sys.argv[1]`. But I guess @MattDMo is right, the way I am trying to make it a json is by this on my server: 

`var newResult3 = JSON.stringify(finalresult[0]);`
`var finalesult2 = JSON.parse(newResult3);`
`return finalesult2;`


where `finalresult[0]` is a result from a sql query.

Comment: @MattDMo I fixed the JSON notation, I have updated it on the code.